# adding time to an uploaded file and database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with adding a  file upload system to my website and I cannot seem to get the file links to match up with the file name that is generated. I am adding a time function onto the front of the file name to make it unique (it generates a number based on the time). It does do this, but for some reason, that unique name is not saved in the database. Could someone help me figure this out?

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "files/"; 
 $target = $target. time(). basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
 echo $target;


//postThis gets all the other information from the form 
 $tfid=$_POST['tfid']; 
 $fname=$_POST['fname']; 
 $lname=$_POST['lname']; 
 $hca=$_POST['hca'];
 $file=($_FILES['photo']['name']);


//Writes the information to the pic table 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO pic
(tfid, file) 
VALUES ('$tfid', '$file')")
or die(mysql_error());
ECHO "<strong>pic table has been saved.<br></strong>";


//Writes the photo to the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ 

//Tells you if its all ok 
echo "<strong>The file has been uploaded</strong>"; 
 } 
else { 

  //Gives an error if its not 
 echo "<strong>Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.</strong>"; 
 } 
 echo '<br>';
require 'insertbuttons.php';
```

Comment: What you have written here adds the time to your file name when it's uploaded? It doesn't look like it would do that.

Comment: More like it adds a randomly generated number on the front of it.I will edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: The code you have here for the `$target` variable seems incorrect. It looks like it would move your file into a folder with the time.

Comment: It does add a number to the names of the files uploaded.If it is the wrong method, however, what would be the correct way to do so?

Comment: I want the file to be moved to a folder. From there, another page creates a hyperlink to it, but the link it creates is one without the number on the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what was going on now. Sorry about the comments. You'll want to save the `$target` variable in your database. The posted variables won't match the target. So, where you have `$file` in your SQL statement, you'll probably want `$target` instead. That should give you the name of the file, but without the extension it looks like.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the trick. I also realized that my link had a second "file/" embedded into it. I took them out and now it works fine.

Comment: @kayle Excellent. Again, sorry about the previous comments. I get going on so many of these questions that my brain goes crazy!